# how to identify browser request if request is coming from same browser?

Tags: php, laravel, browser

I want to identify browser, if request is coming from same browser.

If i get any unique key or similar to that in the browser, how can I retrieve that?.
I am using fingerprint but it only works on single uri, not on the whole browser.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show what you have done so far .

Comment: why did you downvote this? just help me to write it better if you could not understand this. Downvoting is not an option at all.

Comment: i am only asking the way to achieve it, not for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really know what you want but this is a could be used as a start

```
$cookie = Cookie::get("unique");

if($cookie) {
    $fingerprint = $cookie;
    // check fingerprint here
}

if(!$cookie) {
    $fingerprint = "MyFingerprint";
    $cookie = Cookie::forever("unique", $fingerprint);
    Cookie::queue($cookie);
}
```

EDIT:
I don't see a good way of accomplishing this without cookies.
Alternatively you could use the session store or the cache store in the same way but using the ip address as a key, the problem would be that two people from the same ip would count as one

In laravel you could use the method

```
$ip = request()->ip();
```

Comment: That's a great answer but I don't want to use cookie here. Is there any alternate method to achieve the same? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @saksham i updated my answer